# Rails Active record doesnt have X as Y field

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Rails beginner, a query that works on mysql -- select X as Y doesnt seem to be working on rails's query.

count of a field m1 as "cnt" ==> Active record doesnt exist ( query given works on mysql )

```
AB.where("m = 1").group("UNIX_TIMESTAMP(m_timestamp) DIV 6048000 ").select("m_timestamp, count(m1) as cnt")
AB Load (3.5ms)  SELECT m_timestamp, count(m1) as cnt FROM `a_b` WHERE (m = 1) GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(m_timestamp) DIV 6048000 
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<AB id: nil, m_timestamp: "2014-08-01 22:21:09">, #<AB id: nil, m_timestamp: "2014-10-05 00:15:23">, #<AB id: nil, m_timestamp: "2014-12-20 11:55:45">, #<AB id: nil, m_timestamp: "2015-02-04 23:45:29">, #<AB id: nil, m_timestamp: "2015-04-02 03:51:14">, #<AB id: nil, m_timestamp: "2015-06-19 22:25:06">]>
```

The above mysql query -- `SELECT m_timestamp, count(m1) as cnt FROM 'a_b' WHERE (m = 1) GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(m_timestamp) DIV 6048000` works in mysql.

If I use just count, I'll get the grouped counts with some key - I'm not sure what it is.

```
AB.where("m = 1").group("UNIX_TIMESTAMP(m_timestamp) DIV 6048000 ").count
{232=>72, 233=>69, 234=>73, 235=>76, 236=>58, 237=>15}
```

I want the m_timestamp to be the key of the above result. How can I achieve this?

Sample output of mysql result as:

```
mysql> SELECT m_timestamp, count(user_id) as cnt FROM `a_b` WHERE (m = 1) GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(m_timestamp) DIV 6048000  ORDER BY `a_b`.`m_timestamp` ASC;
+---------------------+-----+
| m_timestamp         | cnt |
+---------------------+-----+
| 2014-08-01 22:21:09 |  72 |
| 2014-10-05 00:15:23 |  69 |
| 2014-12-20 11:55:45 |  73 |
| 2015-02-04 23:45:29 |  76 |
| 2015-04-02 03:51:14 |  58 |
| 2015-06-19 22:25:06 |  15 |
+---------------------+-----+

mysql> select * from m_feedbacks LIMIT 5;
+----+-----------+-------+---------------------+---------+
| id | x_id      | m     | m_timestamp         | user_id |
+----+-----------+-------+---------------------+---------+
|  1 |         1 |     1 | 2015-02-04 23:45:29 |       1 |
|  2 |         1 |     2 | 2015-04-24 23:00:37 |       1 |
|  3 |         1 |     2 | 2014-09-25 02:51:37 |       1 |
|  4 |         1 |     0 | 2014-09-29 03:28:01 |       1 |
|  5 |         1 |     0 | 2014-12-11 16:15:09 |       1 |
+----+-----------+-------+---------------------+---------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: A sample dataset to reproduce the problem would be helpful.

Comment: If you're doing conditions on the grouped data you need to using `having` instead of `where`.  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#having

Comment: @MaxWilliams having doesnt apply here. I want all results just in another new field.

Comment: I you want the same output as your mysql query you can try raw sql with rails here is the guide link: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#finding-by-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first approach was close, as `select X as Y` does work. This value is just not displayed by inspect method. Get the first value from the array and call cnt on it to see it is working.

When you call group, the key is the value of the group method calculation.

I think the best way to get what you want, you can use pluck:

```
AB.where("m = 1").group("UNIX_TIMESTAMP(m_timestamp) DIV 6048000 ").pluck("m_timestamp, count(*)").to_h
```

Comment: almost 1 day I wasted trying to figure out where I was going wrong.. Thank you.. Finally got the query and was doing the same in 2 steps. One with pluck and one counts and zipping both together.. U saved a lot of processing.!!

Answer (score 1):

You can achive these by below code

```
AB.where("m = 1").select(m_timestamp as timsatmp , count(*) as count).group("UNIX_TIMESTAMP(m_timestamp) DIV 6048000").inject({}) { |hsh, r| hsh[r.timsatmp] = r.count; hsh }
```

Actully when you getting a count of activerecords then it by default put your group by values in resulting hash as key so it gives your output as:
  {232=>72, 233=>69, 234=>73, 235=>76, 236=>58, 237=>15}

so after getting output from query you needs to create your own hash so it gives hash whatever you required.